# Is it free to use AWS after 12 months?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-deployment

I'm very new to coding and want to deploy my first project. The tutorial I'm watching for deployment (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjYsXuSBZ5U&list=PLSD29KE1Krh9eMhZNnLuicdIs-mg9Ygg7&index=26) is using AWS. I signed up for an account, and the email confirmation that I received states "For the next 12 months, you'll have free access to core AWS compute, storage, database, and application services within the limits of the Free Tier."
Does this mean that after 12 months I'll have to pay? Or is it always free to use the free tier services, even after 12 months?

Comment: To my knowledge, if you stay within the free tier, it should always be free. I've had an AWS account for 3 years that i use to experiment and have never been charged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the service. Some services have a free tier that never expires, e.g. Lambda, and for others the free tier expires after 12 months, e.g. EC2.  You can see the details here: https://aws.amazon.com/free/